# PDO no parameter bound sql error

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; 
session_start(); 
$sqls ="SELECT * FROM markus WHERE user= :c AND id=:id"; 
$result= $handle->prepare($sqls);
$result->bindParam(':c',$_COOKIE['john'],PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resullt execute    (); 
$row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if(!($row)){–  if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['r'] <= 5 ) 
{ $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO markus (bo,us,r,rng) VALUES(:bo,:us,:r,:rng)"; $query = $handle->prepare    ($sql_1); $params = array(':bo'=> $_POST['bo'],':us'=> $_POST['us'],':r'=> $_POST    ['r'],':rng'=> $_POST['rng']); 
$query -> execute($params); echo success }
else { echo nope } } ?>
```

this is the code i have at present
so please help me guys ?????

Comment: You have the placeholder `:john` in the query. But you haven't called `$sqls->bindParam()` to associate a value with it.

Comment: In addittion to what @Barmar said, you should be using parameters for both variables, not a mix of string concatenation and parameters.

Comment: :john is something i should be getting from my html form

Comment: @jonny wish you luck but if you dont make some efforts people will not help you try formatting your code so people can actually read it.

Comment: @Prix ive edited it sorry new to all thyis

Answer (score 2):

You have a placeholder in your query named ":john", this means that you have to fill this placeholder with a correct value, before proceeding, using the "bindParam()" method of your PDO instance.

```
$sqls =$handle->prepare("SELECT * FROM john WHERE user= :cookieJohn AND book_id=:john");
//This lines right under here
$sqls->bindParam(':cookieJohn',$_COOKIE['john']);
$sqls->bindValue(':john',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sqls->execute();
$row  = $sqls -> fetch();
```

Comment: my if statement doenst work though i want to check if the array is empty and if it is empty i wanna do something

Comment: I think this `bindParam(':john',1);` will cause an error, as bindParam expects a reference to a variable, and you're binding a number

Comment: @CodeBird You are completely right! I must have overlooked that, thank you, answer is now edited with correct version.

Comment: @Jonasm he is saying you cannot directly use the number 1 you need to use a variable with the number data. `$sqls->bindValue(':john',$value,PDO::PARAM_INT);` where in your case `$value` would be the 1.

Comment: @Prix - What i am saying is that i changed my code accordingly to CodeBirds findings. Using bindParam, you cannot pass a value, since the paramter is passed by reference, and hence, has to be a variable. "bindValue" is not passed by reference, and are expecting a mixed type argument, therefor it is completely legal to insert a raw value into the argument slot.